# Only want to print the array once - MergeSort

Tags: java, mergesort

Running into an issue with MergeSort. After I sort the array, I want it to only print the fully sorted array, not every pass. My code is below. I am running printArray(intArray) after the array seems to be sorted. Maybe I am putting it in the wrong spot? You can see it in the mergesortComparisons function at the end.

```
private static int merge(int[] intArray, int first, int n1, int n2) {

        int[] temp = new int[n1+n2];
        int copied = 0, copied1 = 0, copied2 = 0;
        while((copied1 < n1) && (copied2 < n2)){
            if (intArray[first + copied1] < intArray[first + n1 + copied2]) 
                temp[copied++] = intArray[first + copied1++];
            else 
                temp[copied++] = intArray[first + n1 + copied2++];
        }

        while(copied1 < n1)
            temp[copied++] = intArray[first + copied1++];
        while(copied2 < n2) 
            temp[copied++] = intArray[first + n1 +copied2++];

        for(int i = 0; i < n1+n2; i++) {
            numComparisons++;
            intArray[first + i] = temp[i];
        }

        return first;
    }

    public static int mergeSortComparisons(int[] intArray, int first, int last){
        int n1, n2;
        if (last > 1){

            n1 = last/2;
            n2 = last - n1;

            mergeSortComparisons(intArray, first, n1);
            mergeSortComparisons(intArray, first + n1, n2);

            merge(intArray, first, n1, n2);
        }

        printArray(intArray);
        return numComparisons;
    }
```

Comment: `printArray(intArray)` will be called as many times as you made recursion calls. Don't print from the recursive method.

Answer (score 1):

Don't print it inside `mergeSortComparisons`. Make a wrapper function and print it there.

```
public static int mergeSort(int[] intArray, int first, int last) {
    int comparisons = mergeSortComparisons(intArray, first, last);
    printArray(intArray);
    return comparisons;
}
```

Wrappers can be useful sometimes.

**Edit:**

If you don't want a wrapper, here's another simple solution:

```
public static int mergeSortComparisons(int[] intArray, int first, int last, boolean wantToPrint){
    int n1, n2;
    if (last > 1){

        n1 = last/2;
        n2 = last - n1;

        mergeSortComparisons(intArray, first, n1, false);
        mergeSortComparisons(intArray, first + n1, n2, false);

        merge(intArray, first, n1, n2);
    }

    if (wantToPrint) {
        printArray(intArray);
    }

    return numComparisons;
}
```

Externally, if you want to print the array, just pass in a value of `true`. This way, you don't need to make a copy of this function that does the same thing without printing the array. It makes printing the array an option.

Comment: what if I didn't want a wrapper?

Comment: You can add a bool argument to the function to determine whether you should print or not. Externally, you would pass in `true`. Inside the function's body, when you recursively call mergeSortComparisons, you would pass in `false`. Not better as a solution than a wrapper though.

Comment: So basically I would be stating wether or not it was solved yet? Where would I put this exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling mergeSortComparisons recursively the call to printArray happens on every pass after every merge. If you return your intArray from the mergeSortComparisons method to the code that called it initially you should be able to call printArray from there and it'll only execute that once.

Comment: I'm confused. Can you clarify further?

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `printArray` within `mergeSortComparisons`, every invocation of `mergeSortComparisons` will have a line of output associated with it. Since `mergeSortComparisons` is recursive, that means you are getting a line of output for every recursive step.

The simplest solution is to remove `printArray` from `mergeSortComparisons` and move it to wherever you are calling `mergeSortComparisons` from initially.

Comment: I'm calling mergeSortComparisons from a different class.